# Carthage, embed third party frameworks in my own framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode6, carthage

I'm building my own iOS framework that I want to make available via Carthage.
It relies on two other frameworks, also installed via Carthage.
When a user installs my framework, does he get the third party frameworks I installed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you add all your Carthage dependencies into your framework's Cartfile. Carthage will use this to resolve your dependencies and download and build them.